# How to reset google analytics fingerprints on a particular desktop?

Tags: javascript, macos, cookies, google-analytics

I have a problem with a particular web application that is using google analytics "userid" features to identify me across different devices that I use.
On one of my devices the web application has stopped working.  It fails due to an excessively long (4+ second) call to the google analytics service, while trying to lookup my utm id.
It doesn't matter which browser I am using and clearing cookies has been no help.
I would like to force google analytics to treat my device as a completely new, never-before-seen device, so that the particular website will start working again on my device.  I am hoping that will solve the problem, much the same as moving to a different computer allows me to continue to use the particular web site (but it's my main desktop that is having the problem and I won't be replacing it any time soon, so changing devices really is not feasible).

So how do I reset google analytics fingerprints on a particular desktop?

Specifics:
The site I am using is cyclo-sphere.com, which works fine until I try to invoke the detailed analysis for a given ride.  Tracing the calls, it always fails after a timeout of 4 seconds while getting my utm id.

The desktop with the problem is Mac Pro running the latest Yosemite and I have been struggling with cyclo-sphere  in Safari, the latest Chrome, and the latest Firefox -- all get tripped up in the same call to the google analytics service.  Another Mac on the same OS works fine as does any PC I have tried.  My iPad and iPhone also work just fine with the particular site.

Here is an example of the call:

https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js

var e=document;window._gaq||eval("var _gaq = [];");_gaq.push(["_provide","inpage_linkid",f]);
function f(c,g){var l=/(?:^__utmli=|; ?__utmli=)([^;]*)/,d=this,m=function(a,b,d,c){var h="addEventListener",k="attachEvent";if(a[h])ah;else if(a[k])ak};this.e=function(){return"; path=/"};var n=c._trackPageview;c._trackPageview=function(a){d.a();d.f&&c.*setXKey(12,1,d.f);n.call(c,a)};this.g=function(){this.i||(this.i=!0,m(e,"click",function(a){d.h(a)}))};this.h=function(a){try{a=a||window.event;var b=a.target||a.srcElement;for(a=0;3>a&&!b.id&&b!=e.body;a++)b=b.parentNode;var c=
b.id||"";d.d(c)}catch(g){}return!0};this.b=function(a,b){f.prototype[a]=b};this.d=function(a){if(a&&100>a.length){a=a.replace(/[^-0-9a-z*:.]/gi,"");var b=new Date((new Date).getTime()+3E4);e.cookie="__utmli="+a+"; expires="+b.toUTCString()+this.e()}else this.a()};this.b("trackClickId",this.d);this.a=function(){e.cookie="__utmli=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT"+this.e()};this.b("deleteClickId",this.a);this.c=function(a){var b=(l.exec(e.cookie)||["",""])[1];a&&a(b);return b};this.b("getClickId",
this.c);this.f=this.c();g.disableAutoTrackLinkId||this.g()};

Here is a related GET that takes many seconds as well:

https://ssl.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.6.3&utms=203&utmn=1172558212&utmhn=cyclo-sphere.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=2560x1440&utmvp=1699x1149&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=16.0%20r0&utmdt=Cyclo-Sphere%20%3A%20My%20Workouts&utmhid=1896742267&utmr=0&utmp=%2Fworkouts&utmht=1424197755860&utmac=UA-37185569-3&utmcc=__utma%3D10456103.1865035456.1422916928.1424041852.1424197003.12%3B%2B__utmz%3D10456103.1422984632.3.2.utmcsr%3Dyoutube.com%7Cutmccn%3D(referral)%7Cutmcmd%3Dreferral%7Cutmcct%3D%2Fwatch%3B&utmjid=&utmu=qAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABE~

Incidentally, I called Pioneer for help getting this reset server-side and they were clueless (they sent me down a path of clearing flash cookies, which I did just to appease them even though I can prove the app doesn't use flash in any way shape or form).

Any advice is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not completely sure I get what you are asking, but Google Analytics works by setting and tracking through cookies, so if you clear your session cookies, then all associations between your browser and GA will be wiped out.

Comment: Thanks, @nyuen.  I did read elsewhere that there is some ability for Google Analytics to track in a cookie-less fashion.  I suspect they are using things like operating system, mac address, etc. to profile the machine and then remembering that on the Google Analytics server side, even without cookies on the client.  I suspect something like that is going on because clearing cookies and changing browsers does not solve the problem.  It is as if Google Analytics is able to fingerprint my machine using the same algorithm and achieving the same result, even without cookies.

Comment: So the question is, how do I get Google Analytics to compute a new fingerprint for my machine, short of me having to change my mac/ethernet address or whatever else it might be using to uniquely identify my desktop machine?

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to get the server side of Google Analytics to disavow any prior knowledge of my machine?  If so, how?